# erroneous pipeline error on rpi camera moodule with gstreamer 1.0 with vp8enc and rtpvp8pay

Tags: webrtc

Hardware :
Rpi Compute 
Camera modules with Fish eye lens

Software :
Gstreamer 1.0

Trying st replace the videotestsrc with camera feed  in this

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! \
    video/x-raw, width=320, height=240, framerate=15/1 ! \
    videoscale ! videorate ! videoconvert ! timeoverlay ! \
    vp8enc error-resilient=true ! \
    rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=6000
```

Have tried using rpicamsrc , v4l2src , ksvideosrc , ximagesrc , however all of them seem to be giving errors .

Any hints will be very appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove `error-resilient=true` and it will work fine.

So try this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! \
video/x-raw, width=320, height=240, framerate=15/1 ! \
videoscale ! videorate ! videoconvert ! timeoverlay ! \
vp8enc ! \
rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=6000
```